# Run executable with variable in Bash

Tags: bash, scripting, echo

I have the following simple script to run an executable:

```
./executable.x -input input.dat << i
input1
input2
i
```

This works perfectly and all is right with the world.  However, I would like to have another script to run multiple tools that require different inputs.  So I'd like to store the above 4 lines in a variable that the script interprets the same.  I tried the following:

```
run_command=$(echo -e "./executable.x -input input.dat << i\ninput1\ninput2\ni")
```

If I echo `$run_command`, it looks right, but it's not interpreted the same.  Any guidance here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Related](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: Use a function: "Variables store data, functions store code."

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
run_command='./executable.x -input input.dat << i
input1
input2
i
'

eval "$run_command"
```